# Every bounded linear operator is an infinitesimal generator

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I'm studying the theory of semigroups from Pazy's book. I'm struggling to understand a specific inequality in the proof of a theorem stating that every bounded linear operator is an infinitesimal generator of some semigroup.

[image]

How does one get the second inequality, which implies that $A$ is indeed the generator of $T$?

Comment: What is your definition of the generator of a semigroup?

Comment: same as in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup

Comment: Ah, sorry. I first misread your question as why the second inequality implied that $A$ is the generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one is familiar with differentiating functions taking values in a Banach space, the second inequality can be obtained as follows.

Define $f:[0,\infty ) \to \mathcal{L}(X)$ by
$$f(t) := T(t) - tA.$$
Note that as $T'(t) = AT(t)$ for each $t\in [0,\infty )$, $f$ is differentiable with $f'(t) = A(T(t) - I)$ for each such $t$.

By applying the mean value inequality from calculus in Banach spaces, for $t>0$,

$$\|f(t) - f(0)\| \leq t \sup_{s\in [0,t]}\|f'(s)\| = t \sup_{s\in [0,t]}\|A(T(s)-I)\| = t\|A\| \sup_{s\in [0,t]}\|T(s) - I\|.$$

Dividing both sides by $t$ and using $\frac{1}{t}(f(t) - f(0)) = \frac{1}{t}(T(t) - I) - A$ obtains the desired inequality.

If the mean value inequality is not a familiar result, it can be obtained in the Banach space case as follows:

$$\|f(t) - f(0)\| = \left\| \int_{0}^{t}f'(s)\,{\rm d}s \right\| \leq \int_{0}^{t}\|f'(s)\|\,{\rm d}s \leq t \sup_{s\in [0,t]}\|f'(s)\|.$$

Comment: The mean value inequality can also be obtained by considering $s\mapsto \varphi(f(s))$ where $\varphi$ is a continuous linear form chosen such that $\varphi(f(t)-f(0)) = \|f(t)-f(0)\|$ and $\|\varphi\| = 1$.

Comment: While you  can use the mean value inequality to deduce the second inequality from Pazy's book, I do not see how you can use this approach to the inequality if the intention is to use it the way Pazy's book immediately does, namely to prove that $T'(0)= A$ (and hence, since $T$ and $A$ commute, $T'(t) = AT(t)$) since one needs to already know what the derivative is to apply the mean value inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: After a previously wrong solution, I wasn't smart enough to obtain the claimed estimate, but something else which also proves to claim that $A$ is the generator.
Hopefully, it's now correct.

So let's calculate the left hand side of your desired inequality.
We have

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(tA)^k}{k!}-I}{t}-A&=\frac 1t \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(tA)^k}{k!}+I-I\right)-A\\&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^{k-1}A^k}{k!}-A\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{t^{k-1}A^k}{k!}+A-A\\
\end{align*}

This follows from writing down terms explicitly for $k=0,1$.

Now, we take norms, use the boundedness of $A$ to take it outside together with the triangle inequality to obtain

\begin{align*}
\left\|\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{t^{k-1}A^k}{k!}\right\|&\leq\|A\|\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{t^{k-1}\|A\|^{k-1}}{k!}\leq \|A\| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^k\|A\|^k}{k!}\\&\leq t\|A\|^2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^{k-1}\|A\|^{k-1}}{k!}\leq t\|A\|^2 \mathrm{e}^{t\|A\|}
\end{align*}

which for $t\to 0$ tends to 0, what we wanted to show.

Comment: How can you use inequality when the terms are operator? What is the partial order on operators?

Comment: Ah, of course, you are correct. I should have written absolute values everywhere, will correct it later.